# Retrieving from a database table a value only if the record does not contain duplicates

Tags: sql

I have a table with the following three values without any other constraints imposed via Schema

```
id_a
id_b
id_c
```

so, there could be more than one row with the same id_b

Now, I want to write a query, that will give me only the rows where id_b is unique and matches a given value.

something like:

```
select * where id_b = ? and (id_b is unique)
```

I know it is simple, but my brain in not working as it should, so any help pls.

Comment: You can try with DISTINCT word. Like select distinct * tablename where id_b = ? and (id_b is unique).

Comment: dont think distinct will help here

Comment: I think you should add more details OR proper explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query:

```
select id_b
from tablename
group by id_b
having count(*) = 1
```

returns all the `id_b`s that you want, so use it with the operator `IN`:

```
select * 
from tablename
where id_b in (
  select id_b
  from tablename
  group by id_b
  having count(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be simpler, assuming you have a primary key.
And you can then add " AND t2.id_b = ..."

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename as t1
  LEFT JOIN tablename as t2 
      ON t1.id_b = t2.id_b AND t1.primarykey <> t2.primarykey
WHERE t2.primarykey IS NULL
```

or this syntax:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tablename as t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'x'
                  FROM tablename as t2 
                  WHERE t1.id_b = t2.id_b AND t1.primarykey <> t2.primarykey)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want rows, use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by b) as cnt_b
      from t
     ) t
where t2.id_b = ? and cnt_b = 1;
```

If you just want the `b` values, use aggregation:

```
select b
from t
group b
having min(b) = max(b) and min(b) = ?;
```